# Can't stop long running query when application stops

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, scheduled-tasks, cascading-deletes

I have a scheduled method in spring application. In this method I try do delete entity by uuid and this operation is long running. When i try to restart application, I see that query is still in execution (after application stopped) and when application tries to start again, my liquibase migration scripts (for example create index if not exists on this table) can't be executed (are in hanging state). 
What's wrong? How can I stop query execution when I stop application? To restart application I do restart postgresql db server now (It's not what i want).

```java
@Component
public class CleanMyEntitiesJob {

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityService myEntityService;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
    public void clean() {
        List<String> entitiesToDelete = myEntityService.getEntitiesToDelete();
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(entitiesToDelete)) {
            entitiesToDelete.stream().forEach(uuid -> {   
                    cameraService.delete(uuid);
            });
        }
    }
}

@Service
public class MyEntityServiceImpl implements MyEntityService {

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

    @Override
    public void delete(String uuid) {
        myEntityRepository.delete(uuid);
    }

    @Override
    public void getEntitiesToDelete(String uuid) {
        ....
    }
}

@Service
public class MyEntityRepository implements extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, String> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("DELETE FROM MyEntity WHERE uuid = ?1")
    void clean(String uuid);
}
```

Comment: Why do you get the entities and then delete one by one... Why not simply delete them in one go instead of doing that one by one (the first will probably complete in a fraction of what you are doing now).

Comment: It is simplified code. I store uuids of entities which are in delete process, because this operation is in scheduled (repeatable) method and I don't want run delete method for items which are already in delete process (delete is long running operation because we have approximately 500k "on delete cascade" entities). Anyway the main problem is that long running query isn't stopped when application stops

Comment: If you can do a `selectIdsToDelete` you can do the same in one go for a delete.

Comment: If the deletion took a few seconds, there would be no question. But the main problem is that when application is stopped, the long running query isn't stopped. And this situation leads to another problems

Comment: I understand what you say. Even if I write a query to delete all records by list of uuids, problem is different. For example, you have a query that takes 2 hours, but there is a need to stop the application. The question is why the query continues to execute.

Comment: Because the query runs on another system, your application is only waiting for output. The query keeps running even if you stop the applicaiton. Not sure if from JDBC you can even stop a running query.

Comment: Understood, thanks. Did you have an experience with cascade removing when it takes a lot of time? I try to do it in background to avoid situations when user waits until such action is finished